# How to duplicate WPF binding type conversion error behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Consider the following:

C#:

```
public class MyVM {
    public double DValue { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding DValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```

The user types "asdf" in the box. That can't be converted to a `double`, so you see the error template on the text box -- it gets a red border around it.

The classic problem with numeric text inputs that validate on keydown is that if the user types "-", that's not a valid numeric value. If the user completes the value as "-1" that's fine, but the textbox already threw a fit.

One workaround is to give the ViewModel a `StringDValue` property which treats "-" and "" as 0, keeps the `DValue` property correctly updated, and so on. You can make that work. A value converter is problematic because the thing goes both ways: User types "-", 0 goes back to the ViewModel property, `OnPropertyChanged` is fired, 0 travels back, and you get a zero in the text box. I'd imagine that's workaroundable as well, but that's not the path I chose here.

## So here's the question:

The trouble is what happens when the user types "asdf". How can `StringDValue` tell the `Binding` that the value is invalid input? Is there some exception you can throw that the binding will catch and treat as a non-crashing input error? Every exception type I throw is uncaught in the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have been obvious.

The answer is to write a [ValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx), as in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14481386/424129

C#

```
public class NumericInputTextValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var s = (value ?? "").ToString().Trim();

        double d;

        var valid = s == "-" || s == "+" || s == "" || double.TryParse(s, out d);

        if (!valid)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a Number");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, "");
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="StringDValue" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <MyNS:NumericInputTextValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```