# How can I add ValidationRules to a WPF Binding inline?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, validationrules

I know how to define ValidationRules using nested elements (e.g. [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/948/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules)) but how can I do it inline? I.e.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, ValidationRules=???, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" >
```

I tried `ValidationRules={StaticResource CashAmountRule}` where CashAmountRule points to my custom validation rule class but the compiler complains it is not a Collection value.  How can I make it one?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible:

> The following are properties of Binding that cannot be set using the `Binding` markup extension/`{Binding}` expression form.
>
> - [...]
> - ValidationRules: the property takes a generic collection of ValidationRule objects. This could be expressed as a property element in a Binding object element, but has no readily available attribute-parsing technique for usage in a Binding expression. See reference topic for ValidationRules.
> - [...]

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/binding-markup-extension)

Answer (score -6):

You need to implement ValidationRule in your model.  Here's a link to get you started:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481240/validationrule-for-wpf-textbox)

Comment: totally ignoring the question