# How to set TextBox MaxLength to 4, but only if the number is negative, otherwise 3, in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm kind of stuck here.

So what I need is - I have `TextBox` that can only have the values from `-999` to `999`. I've tried setting the boundaries like so.

```
<TextBox Height="{Binding ElementName= SomeComboBox, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                     Tag="int"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     MaxLength="4"
                                     Margin="2, 4, 0, 0"
                                     AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Something_cbSome">
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <behaviors:TextBoxIntInputBehavior AllowNegative="True" />
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Something"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                                             TargetNullValue="">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <validation:IntRangeRule Min="-999"
                                                                     Max="999" />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
```

But the obviously now someone can enter 4 digits since the `MaxLength` has the value `4`. For example `1234` which is higher than the `999`.

Also, this allows me to type in things like `---`, `8--2` etc.

Desired accepted values : `-999` up to `999`. No more, no less. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post your validation rule? Cause it should not allow more than max value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

1. You alternatively may use a slider (the another control, it is bad)
2. Or you can see the ValidationRule class in an another question: [ValidationRule for WPF Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481240/validationrule-for-wpf-textbox)

Reuse it!

Comment: What you provided, IMO, belongs more to the "comment" section, instead of "answer". Anyways, thanks for the link.

Comment: @aca have a look at what it actually says, then you can decide if it is more of a comment. There is a good advice here and in fact it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TextBox PreviewTextInput="NumericTextHandler" />

   private void NumericTextHandler(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Text == "-" && ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 0)
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (!int.TryParse(e.Text, out _))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var newText = ((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text;
                if (int.TryParse(newText, out var newValue))
                {
                    e.Handled = newValue is < -999 or > 999;
                }
            }
        }
```

You could handle The PreviewTextInput event of the Textbox to only accept
minus and int as first char.
And only values from -999 to 999.
This might be an easy alternative that could work for your purpose.

Comment: You need to stop/check copy paste as well or you can paste in whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting the logic into the view model:

```
    public class MainViewModel : Binding
    {
        string _MyNumber;
        int _MyValidatedNumber;
        public string MyNumber
        {
            get { return _MyNumber; }
            set
            {
                _MyNumber = value;
                
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MyNumber))
                {
                    _MyValidatedNumber = 0;
                    _MyNumber = "";
                }
                else if(_MyNumber== "-")
                {
                    _MyValidatedNumber = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int temp;
                    if (int.TryParse(_MyNumber, out temp) && (temp <= 999 && temp >= -999))
                    {
                        _MyValidatedNumber = temp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _MyNumber = _MyValidatedNumber.ToString();
                    }
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyNumber));
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyValidatedNumber));

            }
        }
        public int MyValidatedNumber
        {
            get { return _MyValidatedNumber; }
            set { _MyValidatedNumber = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyValidatedNumber)); }
        }
    }
```

I use here 2 properties . One for the as-is text and the second one for the validated value.

The XAML code looks as following:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:MainViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBox 
            Text="{Binding MyNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     MaxLength="4"
                                     Margin="2, 4, 0, 0"
                                     AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Something_cbSome"
            ToolTip="{Binding MyValidatedNumber}"
            >
            
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```